# Rails guard running out of memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, guard

I'm fairly new to Rails development, but I'm having a big problem with guard.  I'm using guard to automatically test my application and I'm constantly getting the following error messsage

```
[FATAL] failed to allocate memory
```

Does anyone know what's causing this?

I'm on a Windows 7 x64 machine using Ruby 1.9.3 and the latest version of guard.

[EDIT]

It would appear that after I removed the wdm gem this error no longer occurs.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer, it is covered [here](https://github.com/Maher4Ever/wdm/pull/7).